# Javascript Selected Formatting not working in browser while in dreamweaver it does

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with this script. It is suposed to add html tags to a selected text region in a text box.
While live viewing in dreamweaver it works just fine. Exactly how it's suposed to. In browser it does nothing.

Any thoughts?

The function is called with `onclick="formatText(content,'b')"`.

```
function formatText(el, tag) {
    var selectedText = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text
            : el.value.substring(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
    alert(selectedText);
    if (selectedText != '') {
        var newText = '<' + tag + '>' + selectedText + '</' + tag + '>';
        el.value = el.value.replace(selectedText, newText);
        document.getElementById(el).focus();
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById(tag).value == "0") {
            document.getElementById(tag).value = "1";
            document.getElementById(el).value = document.getElementById(el).value
                    + "<" + tag + ">";
            document.getElementById(el).focus();
        } else {
            document.getElementById(tag).value = "0";
            document.getElementById(el).value = document.getElementById(el).value
                    + "</" + tag + ">";
            document.getElementById(el).focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you might want to look into using would be jQuery, it has built in functionality to do most of the things that you're going to want to do. It's worth your time learning. ( see http://jquery.com/ )

With that being said, I edited your code some. You will need to change your "onclick" event to "onmousedown", leaving it as "onclick" will remove your selected text focus, and your method won't work.. I'm unsure what your else statement is supposed to do, so I didn't update that at all. Hopefully this helps some.

Cheers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function formatText( el , tag )
{
    var selectedText = "" + document.getSelection();

    if ( selectedText.length > 0 )
    {
        var textWithTag = "&lt;" + tag + "&gt;" + selectedText + "&lt;/" + tag + "&gt;";
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace( selectedText , textWithTag );
    }
}

</script>

<div id="test">Something</div>
<div onmousedown='formatText( document.getElementById("test") , "span style=\"color:red\"" );'>Click</div>
```